# Nuxt.js app doesn't load charts or maps when copying and pasting a link into a new browser tab, otherwise works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Vue.js / Nuxt.js app running at https://sqwyre.com.

For a given user workflow:

1. Search for something, e.g. Birmingham
2. Click 'search' and get a list of results
3. Click on anything, e.g. [First entry, for University of Birmingham](https://sqwyre.com/location/E08000025/kVZIXpjqmJrfmLHdIG7FFS7C/)
4. See the displayed report, which includes all charts:

[image: Expected report for University Of Birmingham At Birmingham Womens Hospital, Metchley Park Road, Birmingham, B15 2TE]

5. Alternatively, view the map:

[image: Expected map view]

That all works exactly as expected. However, if you were instead to copy and paste (or follow) the below urls you would not see the charts or the maps:

1. Copying and pasting / clicking the report link in a new browser tab: https://sqwyre.com/location/E08000025/kVZIXpjqmJrfmLHdIG7FFS7C/

[image: Unexpected report, not displaying charts]

2. The same happens with the link to the map view: https://sqwyre.com/map/E08000025/kVZIXpjqmJrfmLHdIG7FFS7C/

This behaviour is irrespective of browser (tested the above on Chrome, Edge and Firefox). The page, apart from displaying the loaded text, is entirely non-functional (links don't work, interactive behaviours do nothing).

Note, though, if you use the search url (https://sqwyre.com/search/?search=Birmingham) and click on the subsequent search result links, then reports display as expected.

The unexpected behaviour does not occur on test, only on build, and the only - rather obscure - error message I get is as follows:

```
> TypeError: "t is undefined" [nuxt] Error while initializing app
> DOMException: "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the
> hierarchy"
```

I don't have any 't' variables, so I'm assuming this has something to do with the way Nuxt loads its own javascript, but beyond that I'm at a complete loss as to where to start or how to describe the issue beyond this workflow.

I'm happy to provide additional info, code snippets, whatever, and would appreciate guidance on how to fix this.

Comment: It seems like your data differs on server vs client. They should be same otherwise errors will happen.

Comment: No, identical data, all accessed via the same API, so no variation. As mentioned, this isn't about pages not loading, it is about pages not loading if I gave you a link to follow.

Comment: I am talking about data hydration. Vue hydrate data from server state to client state. And it should match. When it dont mathc such errors as on your page will be thrown

Comment: OK, worth exploring, but how do I diagnose that with the error message I'm getting? And the map is really only a snippet of code to put a single coordinate on an OpenStreetMap view. Plus, why does it work one way, but not another? The context of the link is different, but it's still just a link.

Comment: When you open link directly it do ssr rehydration, when u go via link this dont happen because server dont get hit. You can go to nuxt discord to discuss it